# how to Get Current Location On Google Map android

Tags: android-maps-v2

I'm having some trouble when I want to get current location on Google Maps Android.

I have 2 class activity this `LokasiActivity` http://pastebin.com/ECr9G7Vq

and this maps activity http://pastebin.com/e3zruznk

The problem is, I want to change `-6.8603727, 108.6564165` value automatically based on user's current position. Can I do that?

Comment: what exactly is your problem? You have posted a code that is not verifiable.

Answer (score 1):

So, the actual problem looks like you never pass the user's last location from the first activity to the map activity. Put it in the bundle extras when starting it, then retrieve in map activity's `oncreate()`.